# Alignment of Text not working on TextFlow

Tags: text, javafx, alignment, textflow

I am new to javafx.

I am trying to build a messenger where the chatting panel show messages.
I want to align the messages like my own messages are on left and other messages are on right.

To display the message i am using TextFlow where I add Text. But the alignment isnt working.

```
TextFLow tf=new TextFlow();
Text t1= new Text("Hi");
Text t2= new Text("Hello");
t1.setTextAlignment(TextAlignment.RIGHT);
t2.setTextAlignment(TextAlignment.LEFT);
tf.getChildren().addAll(t1,t2);
```

But the alignment not working. Both the text are on left.
What should I do?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can set the TextAlignement from the TextFlow but, **i don't think** we could have two alignment in the same container, however, you can use a tricky way to skirt this problem by using Labels & VBox:

```
private VBox Chat(){

    VBox chat = new VBox();
    chat.setPrefSize(400, 400);
    chat.setStyle("-fx-background-color:#333333;");

    Label txt1 = new Label("Text1");
    txt1.setTextFill(Color.WHITE); 
    txt1.setPrefWidth(400); 
    txt1.setAlignment(Pos.CENTER_LEFT);

    Label txt2 = new Label("Text2");
    txt2.setTextFill(Color.WHITE); 
    txt2.setPrefWidth(400); 
    txt2.setAlignment(Pos.CENTER_RIGHT);  

    chat.getChildren().addAll(txt1,txt2);

    return chat;
}
```

Why **Label** ? This node work in the same way as the Text node but the advantage is that wet can resize the background.

Why **VBox** ? is optional, even if i think **TextFlow** is better suited to textual nodes. It is also for the positioning, VBox is more suited for classified items from top to bottom **chatting panel**. Good luck !